# Adding +1 in the end of the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, if-statement, checkbox

I have been studying JavaScript/JQuery lately on my free time. I am trying to make script choose between 2 checkboxes. If first checkbox is true then the second is false, if first one is false then second is true. This one works but it doesn't work on multiple classes. I have added 2 classes .checkbox-group1 and .checkbox-group2. I tried to make script add +1 to .checkbox-group 2 times but it only adds so I would get classes .checkbox-group1 and .checkbox-group2 but I only get .checkbox-group1.

Javascript/JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var i = 0;

if(i<2){

i++;

}

else{

i = 1;

}
    
    $('.checkbox-group'+ i +' input:checkbox').click(function() {
    $('.checkbox-group'+ i +' input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

HTML CHECKBOXES

```
<div class="checkbox-group1 required">
Yes: <input type="checkbox">
No: <input type="checkbox">
</div>


<div class="checkbox-group2 required">
yes: <input type="checkbox">
No: <input type="checkbox" >
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like you're looking for [<input type="radio">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) which only allows a single option selected at once.

Comment: Dude.... Sometimes the solution is so easy and I am here trying to reinvent the wheel. Post this as an answer an I'll accept that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need a loop, you can get the right checkbox in a var and then set all checkbox of the div to false. Finally, you set the right one to checked.

I commented my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // we get div with class name starting like : checkbox-group
    $("div[class^='checkbox-group'],div[class*='checkbox-group']").click(function(event) {
      // we save current clicked element in a var
      var getCurrentChecked = event.target; 
      // we set all input checked to false
      $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
      // then we check the right one
      $(getCurrentChecked).prop('checked', true);
      
      console.log($(this).attr('class') + ' - ' + $(getCurrentChecked).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML CHECKBOXES

<div class="checkbox-group1 required">
Yes: <input type="checkbox" value="0">
No: <input type="checkbox" value="1">
</div>


<div class="checkbox-group2 required">
yes: <input type="checkbox" value="0">
No: <input type="checkbox" value="1">
</div>
```

Comment: Be wary of using this though, as clicking the containing div outside the checkbox will uncheck that box.